# Unable to receive language text from server to client

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, frontend, server-side

I wanted to store Indian language and again display the message saved.(CRUD operation with language message). I was able to achieve create, but when try to read i get "???" instead of language content that was saved(i.e, नमस्ते
). So When i debug i find the data till print writer object is as expected its showing in language. But when i receive in my Ajax on javascript. i get "????".

**Note :** 
I tried content-type - text/html, application/json.
Encoding is UTF-8

At server:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("x-xss-protection", "1; mode=block");
response.setHeader("x-frame-options", "SAMEORIGIN");

out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write("नमस्ते");// this is coming from db
```

At Client

```
$.get({
   url: "/server/langMsg",
}).then(function(rspTxt){
   var json = $.parseJSON(rspTxt);
});
```

Comment: Something here is unclear.  Assuming `response` is a `ServletResponse` or `HttpServletResponse`, then `getOutputStream()` returns a subclass of `OutputStream` in which `write()` accepts bytes (i.e. `byte[]`) and NOT a `String`.   So the code as you show should not compile.  To get from characters, which are UTF-16 internally to UTF-8 will require an encoding conversion from `String` to `byte[]`.  Please show us the REAL code that is producing the wrong encoding, i.e. how you fetched from the database and the declaration of the object you pass to `write()`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `ServletOutputStream`. Simply use `javax.servlet.PrintWriter`,

```
response.getWriter().print("नमस्ते");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for  DB, I have tried with MySQL. But, I guess should be same.
 if you not specified  UTF8, you should see something like ?????? in ur DB else 
 you should see the hindi data. if you not specified ,specify and try.
 Quick Code:
 First check for UTF8 compatibility with this query. If it supports you should 
 see the output as “Character_set_system”| “UTF8”
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE ‘character_set_system’;

Now that being checked, alter the table and just modify the column, specify it 
 as UTF8

ALTER TABLE tableName MODIFY columnname VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET UTF8;
 Now, try to insert the hindi/local language value and save it. Query it and u 
 should see the hindi text.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my answer, the issue was with tomcat and mysql configuration(context.xml in my project).

- First of tomcat server.xml "Connection" tag should be having encryption="UTF-8"
- Second of in context.xml when giving url of mysql need to append"?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8" which is specifying unicode and encoding.